Is it easier to compute discrete logarithms resulting from a point addition?
Let’s say I have 2 publicly known randomly sampled points $G_1$ and $G_2$ belonging to a short Weirestrass prime curve with prime order. Let’s say I have $G_3=G_1+G_2$ and a scalar $s$ such as $G_3=[s]G_1$.
Are there faster ways to compute $s$ by knowing all the elliptic curve points involved ? Of course, without determining the discrete logarithm between $G_1$ and $G_2$ nor any other discrete logarithm in general to help find $s$?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

From Dlog to $Ps$
Let's assume that we have an oracle ( program) that solves (efficiently) the Discrete Log (Dlog) on the given curve, then we can solve $s$ with this oracle.
now, with a bit of confusing terminology ( Reading reduction from books is advised)

The problem of finding $s$ (let's call it $Ps$) is at least as easy as Dlog on this curve. Or, in the other direction
Finding the $Ps$ is as hard, then Dlog must be hard.

From $Ps$ to Dlog
Let's assume that another oracle gives us $s$ (efficiently) from $G_3=[s]G_1$. Then we can use this as
$$G_3 = [s]G_1 = G_1+G_2$$ this implies
$$[s]G_1 - G_1 = G_2$$
$$[s-1]G_1 = G_2$$
so we found DLog of $G_2$ to the base $G_1$
Now, use this oracle, and instead of $G_1$ use $G$. This oracle solves the DLOG to the base $G$. Since we solved in one base, we can solve for any base. Now, just the other around;

Dlog is at least as easy as  $Ps$ on this curve. Or, in the other direction
Finding Dlog is as hard, then $Ps$ must be hard.

The equivalence
With the two way around we have equality, i.e. Dlog and $Ps$ are equivalent problems.
